# Saving a generated QR code png but getting 404 Not Found error message

Tags: php, html, jquery, qr-code

I am trying to generate a QR code from the value of a HTML input element:

HTML, CSS, and JS Code:

**index.php**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="https://codingbirdsonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/cropped-coding-birds-favicon-2-1-192x192.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-LtrjvnR4Twt/qOuYxE721u19sVFLVSA4hf/rRt6PrZTmiPltdZcI7q7PXQBYTKyf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Send Email Example</title>
    <style>
        .center-block {
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-5 mx-auto">
            <div class="card card-signin my-5">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title text-center">Generate QR Code</h5>

                    <form id="generateQrForm" class="form-signin">
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail">Text For QR <span style="color: #FF0000">*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" name="qrText" id="qrText" class="form-control" required placeholder="Enter something to generate QR">
                        </div> <br/>
                       <div id="generatedQr text-center">
                            <img src="" id="generatedQrImg" class="center-block">
                        </div> <br/>
                        <button type="submit" name="generateQrBtn" id="generateQrBtn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase" >Generate QR</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="generate_qr_js.js"></script>
  </script>

</body>
```

jQuery code:

**generate_qr_js.js**

```
$("form#generateQrForm").on("submit",function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    var qrText = $("#qrText").val();
    $.post("generate_qr_script.php",{generateQr:'generateQr',qrText:qrText},function (response) {
    var data = response.split('^');
    var generateQrImgPath = data[1];
    $("#generatedQrImg").attr("src",generateQrImgPath);
    })
});
```

PHP Code:

**generate_qr_script.php**

```
<?php
include "library/phpqrcode/qrlib.php";
if (isset($_POST['generateQr']) == 'generateQr')
{
    $qrText = $_POST['qrText']; // receive the text for QR
    $directory = "generated_qr/"; // folder where to store QR
    $fileName = 'QR'.rand().'.png'; // generate random name of QR image
    QRcode::png($qrText, $directory.$fileName, 'L', 4, 2); // library function to generate QR
    echo "success^".$directory.$fileName; // returns the qr-image path
}
?>
```

I run these 3 codes under one folder along with [phpqrcode](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpqrcode/files/) library that is imported in **generate_qr_script.php** file. When I go to the index.php website using XAMPP server, I get an error saying "404 Not Found" as shown below:

[image: 404 Not Found]

When I inspect the source code, the image source is generated successfully but it doesn't get shown on the web.

[image: Image source not loading]

What I am trying to do is to generate a QR code that captures what the user inputs into the text box that is written in the HTML code. Ideally, it would be nice to store the barcode into the local computer file within the same folder but the code does not load the desired QR code png.

If anyone has any suggestions on where I am going wrong or has a better idea to generate a barcode please do let me know.

Comment: Can you find the .png file on the server?  Maybe you need a forward slash or / at the start of the url?  If you type the url in the browser, can you see the image?  What do you mean by "local computer file"?  On the client's machine?

Comment: By local computer, I mean on my macbook laptop where I want to save the .png file. I have loaded the url on the browser but I get same error. The image does not even appear in the folder that I want to save it to, so the server doesn't know what to load probably. I have also tried the / at the start of the url but nothing changed.

Comment: So, this is a PHP server script problem. Are there any server error logs?  I would repost this question without any client side  information or details  and just try to get help creating the image on the server first.

Comment: I think I fixed it by changing the file permission where I wanted to save the images somehow! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed it by changing the file permission where I wanted to save the images somehow!